# Insert to database with javascript on click with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to insert data in my database when I click an element, on the element I got a function which gets some data from it. Then I want to insert that data + some more to my database, like this:

```
 function insertItem(x)
  {     
    var Aktiv = "Bokad";      
    var tid = x.dataset.tid;
    var dag = x.dataset.dag;
    var namn = "Filip";
    var url = '/insert/' + Aktiv + '/' + tid + '/' + dag + '/' + namn;
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(result){
    console.log(result);
      },
      error: function(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
    });    
  }
```

Then in my node file I think I should retrive it like this:

```
app.post('/insert/:Aktiv/:dag/:namn/:tid', function(req, res){
pool.connect(function(err, bokad, done){

 if(err){
     return console.error('error fetching bokad inserted', err);
 }
 bokad.query("INSERT INTO bokad(aktiv, dag, namn, tid) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4)",
 [req.body.Aktiv, req.body.dag, req.body.namn, req.body.tid]);
 console.log(req.body.Aktiv);

done();
res.redirect('/');
});
});
```

Element I click contains this

```
<td onclick = "insertItem(this)" data-dag = "<%= bord.rows[19].dag %>" data-tid = "<%= bord.rows[19].tid %>" class = "<%= bord.rows[19].Aktiv %>"></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your post route you can see that you declared parameter variables: :Aktiv. You would also have to do this with dag, namn, tid. with a **:** before it.

There are multiple ways of sending information with a http request. I would not do this with params. But I would put it in the body of your request and access it with req.body[variabel]. If you would send your variables in the body of the POST request please do not forget to add your body parsers, if it would be a normal form: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded, if it would be as JSON: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json

If you want to do it with params you have to access them with req.params[variable name], eg: req.params.Aktiv.

I suggest reading: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters and https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params

Good luck! I hope this helped.

Comment: I dont understand body parser tho, my data is inserted in my database now, however all is undefined:D

Comment: @Filip A body parser looks at the incoming post request and puts it in req.body so you can access your variables there. Express does this so you do not need to worry about the how.

Comment: @Filip What library are you using to insert the row into your database. Also can you please console.log all your variables in the front end and back end.

Comment: Sweet okey, I consoled log my req.body.Aktiv and its undefined, and when I consol.log my ajax success result it returns my entire html code of some reason

Comment: @Filip If you want to keep using params in stead of a body you have to use req.params.Aktiv, ...

Comment: @Filip Also I think you are doing it wrong. You should use x.getAttribute(''data-tag"), ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

Comment: No params seemed to do the trick actaully, and it also told me I mixed up some position since in my function I got my name in the last place and in server.js I got tid there. Thanks alot for your time and help!!:)